# Debugging Typescript with NetBeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans, typescript, breakpoints, everlaw-plugin

I have Netbeans 8.2 RC which claims to support sourcemaps for JS debugging, allowing transpiler use. I'm using the Everlaw plugin for Typescript.

I'd expect to be able - as a start - to set breakpoints in the .ts files, but clicking in the margin does nothing. Is this "not yet supported", or are there additional configuration steps needed?

My `tsconfig.json` already contains

```
"sourceMap": true
```

Comment: wouldn't this be better answered by the people that make the Everlaw plugin?

Comment: @toskv - Quite possibly, but there's no specific support forum as it's basically just a github repository. I wouldn't be surprised if they frequented SO anyway...